# Can I dynamically create a link to my plugin settings/options page from my plugin description?

Tags: plugin-development

Currently, in my plugin description, I'm hardcoding...

> To customize options <a
>   href="options-general.php?page=my-plugin-admin.php">click
>   here</a>

Is there a dynamic method to call the plugin options page?

Comment: @Scott B: - I may be drawing a blank, but my answer is *"No"*...

Comment: Maybe he means the "Settings" link that some pluings have in the plugins list?

Comment: Are you talking about something like this? http://wpengineer.com/1295/meta-links-for-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: @Zack & @t310s: YES! Please make it an answer so I can give credit :)

Comment: If he doesn't make it an answer, I'll go ahead and make the answer. Want to give him time to post it since he provided the actual answer.

Comment: Done as requested.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a plugin settings link that's dynamically generated.

This would be one approach.
http://wpengineer.com/1295/meta-links-for-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: To be honest, i wouldn't actually suggest the file name as the handle for a plugin(though i'm not suggesting it's wrong), it was just the first decent example i found with a quick google. I'll add my own example in due course..

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way I know to do it from code

```
add_filter('plugin_action_links_'.plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'salcode_add_plugin_page_settings_link');
function salcode_add_plugin_page_settings_link( $links ) {
    $links[] = '<a href="' .
        admin_url( 'options-general.php?page=my-plugin' ) .
        '">' . __('Settings') . '</a>';
     return $links;
}
```

from http://salferrarello.com/wordpress-plugin-add-settings-link/

Comment: Link only answers are a bad habit to get into. What if the link dies or the website goes down? If something like that happens it will render this answer useless. Better to use the code in the website and bring it over here, then give credit where credit is due by linking to where you found it. You can click the `Edit` button underneath your answer to add your code.